# Magento 2 How to make changes to Bundle product edit detail page?

Tags: magento2, product, product-view, bundle-product, product-edit

I want to make some changes to bundle product detail page.

I found a module in my theme which has this Reference Block for bundle addtocart .

Magento_Bundle/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customize.button">
            <action method="setTemplate">
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/customize.phtml</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.addtocart.bundle">
            <action method="setTemplate">
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Bundle::catalog/product/view/bundleaddtocart.phtml</argument>
           </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

How can I do it for Edit bundle which comes from edit action on mini cart for bundle product.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at this [file](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Bundle/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_bundle.xml) and override same within your own module in

> app/code

or

> app/design